# Switching coordinates of affine variety, what happens to dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have an affine variety $V \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ (not necessarily irreducible). Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and let us define another affine variety 
$$
W = \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n : (x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}) \in V.
$$
Does it then follow that $\dim W = \dim V$? Any comments or explanations are appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $f_\sigma: \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, $x_i \mapsto x_{\sigma(i)}$ is easily seen to be a ring automorphism, with inverse corresponding to the permutation $\sigma^{-1}$. The ideals corresponding to these two varieties will just be images/inverse images of each other under $f_\sigma$ or $f_{\sigma^{-1}}$, and so "everything about them" should be the same. By this I mean that the ideal of one can be pushed through $f_\sigma$ and viewed in an isomorphic ring, and so anything that has a ring-theoretic interpretation (like dimension) will have to be the same.